# Asp :RangeValidator and Asp:RegularExpressionValidator both fired simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have Asp:TextBox,Asp:RegularExpressionValidator and Asp:RangeValidator on .aspx page.

These two validators have ControlToValidate value equal to textBox Id.

RegularExpressionValidator have validation Expression such that it allows only number.

Range validator have maximum value ="100" and if I enter any text then both validators get fired .

Logically only RegularExpressionValidator should fire if I enter any textvalue.

Is there any property of Range validator such that it check for numeric value to compare and disbled if value entered in textBox is some text so that no handling of event(Client side and Server side both) is required.

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

add this part to your RangeValidator

```
 Type="Integer"
```

and let me know if this was the cause.